# How to skip an if statement to go to the next if statement

Tags: java

Is it possible to skip an if statement and execute another if statement inside that if statement?

```
if(...){
    A code.
}else if(...){
    B. Call to C.
}else if(...){
    C code.
}else(...){
    D code.
}
```

E.g. if I am in the if statement containing A, and the conditions change so that B is executed, how would I call the code in C **WHILST** in the B else if statement.

EDIT = Forgot to say that my if statements apart from one returned a custom object array called Dice[]. I have implemented the below solutions and now getting a return statement error.

```
public Die[] ifA(){
A
}

public void ifB(){
ifC(); ifD();
}
public Die[] ifC(){
C
}
public Die[] ifD(){
D
}

public Die[] roll(){

if(...){ return ifA();
}else if(...){ifC();ifD();
}else if(...){return ifC();    
}else(...){return ifD();
}

}
```

I'm just getting a return error at the end of the roll() method. Surely I shouldn't as I used the else{} block therefore the else WILL have to run if no if/else if statement is executed, no?

EDIT #2 = Just found a workaround for the method that did not return a value. Thanks guys for your input. Made my code a lot neater and understandable!

Comment: You might want to format your code first...

Comment: instead of skipping make the `C code` a module so you can call it within `B` statement or `C` statement

Comment: Not unless you change them all to individual `if` statements to all be checked for a situation like that

Comment: By "Call to C" do you mean make a method named `doC()` and call that inside the second and third `if`?

Comment: Use methods to do stuff.

Comment: @cricket_007 I mean execute the code in C. the code in C is not a method, just statements

Comment: Well, what I suggested seems to be what these answers are doing, so you may want to clarify that to the others.

Comment: In your edits, your error is referring to the first `else if`. There is no `return` there. Also, you are missing a semi-colon on `ifD()` at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could put your `A Code`, `B Code`, `C Code`, and `D Code` in their own methods and then call the `C Code` while in the `B` if statement.

For Example

```
public void doA() {
    //Do what would happen in A
}
public void doB() {
    //Do what would happen in B
}
public void doC() {
    //Do what would happen in C
}
public void doD() {
    //Do what would happen in D
}
```

and for the if-else-block

```
if (...) {
    doA();
} else if (...) {
    doB();
    doC();
} else if (...) {
    doC();
} else {
    doD();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. So far I've done everything and im just getting a return error. I probably forgot to say that my if statements apart from one all returned something. Now that I've done your step, I'm getting a return error but not sure what to return. I've put my previous if statements in it individual method and put a the if-else block in a method. I'll edit my post so you can see what I mean

Comment: You are missing some semi-colons after most of the `doX()` methods

Answer (score 4):

Create a method for the c Code.

```
if(...){
    A code.
}else if(...){
    B
    cCode();
}else if(...){
    cCode();
}else(...){
    D code.
}


private void cCode() {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the other two answers are cleaner, but just throwing another way out there.

```
int condition = 2;
while(true) {
    if(condition == 1){
        System.out.println(1);

    }else if (condition == 2){
        System.out.println(2);
        condition = 3;
        continue;

    }else if (condition == 3){
        System.out.println(3);

    }

    break; //if continue gets called it will skip this
}
```

Comment: You could change this and remove the `else`s to make there not have to be a while loop and `continue`.